# fputcsv inserting extra "

Tags: php, csv, encoding

I realized that strings which contains spaces are inserted on the csv file with an extra " at the beginning and at the end

```
if (!file_exists("./csv/file.csv")) {
    $header = array("Arbol completo","Títol","Code","Parent Code","Servei","Urgència per defecte","Impacte","No es pot sol·licitar","Flux de Treball","SLA","Grup Resolutor-1","Grupo responsable catalogo","Informació","Documentació","Descripció","Llista autoritzats","Icona","Caracteristica", "Valor");
    $fp = fopen("./csv/catalogo_de _peticiones_de_servicio.csv", "w");
    fprintf($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)));
    fputcsv($fp, $header,";");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

it's somthing wrog ,it doens't have enconding problems I'm usen utf-8 charset

Comment: That's expected, see the [docs](http://php.net/fputcsv). What is the actual issue?

Comment: [RFC 4180 (the closest thing that exists to a formal CSV specification)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) - see section 2 and bullets 5,6,7.... it isn't simply strings that contain spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify enclosure as blank which is the 4th optional parameter of `fputcsv`. Default enclosure is `"`

```
fputcsv($fp, $header,";", '');
```

[Reference Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: I can't set the delimiter like `''`' its has to be `' '` ,There is any way to set not set a delimiter like `''`??

Comment: Delimiter in your case is `;`. I am talking about enclosure to be removed.

Comment: Sorry ,its de enclosure , with `fputcsv($fp, $header,";",chr(0));` has an extra space too

Comment: Don't add space. Add `''` no space in between.

Comment: with `''` I get `enclosure must be a character`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Doing multiple stuff at the same time. Yes enclosure must contain one character. You can eliminate double quotes while reading the file with `fgetcsv` or when you open a file with any spreadsheet editor. Specify enclosure as `"` and your file will be clean.